# Mocha/Chai testing in react/ redux: Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, redux, react-redux, chai

I was originally doing mocha/chai testing. It was fine until I try to use react simulate, then mocha/chai seems to stop working. Now I don't even get to see how many test has pass or fail.

For some of my test case, they kept returning the following:

`Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`

Comment: Can you attach one of your error test case code?

Answer (score 0):

You should apply thunk middleware to your redux store.
Here is how I do it during testing:

```
 import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
 import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';

 describe('Your test', () => {
   const mockStore = configureStore([thunk]);

   it('success case', () => {
     const store = mockStore({});

     return store.dispatch(yourAsyncFunction()).then(() => {
       const action = store.getActions()[0];

       expect(action.type).to.equal(EXPECTED_ACTION);
     });
   });
 });
```